# Session ID changes although resave has been set to true (the client doesn't take the new expiration date into account)

Tags: express, session, redis, session-cookies, express-session

I'm using NodeJS an express session handling with Redis. Here is the interesting part:

```
let session = require('express-session')
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
let Redis = require('ioredis');
let clientRedis = new Redis();
let RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

const SESSIONSECRET = require(config.get('app.secretsession')).secret;
app.use(cookieParser(SESSIONSECRET));

const sessionMiddleware = session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    client: clientRedis,
  }),
  secret: SESSIONSECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 30000,
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: config.get('app.domainecookie')
   }
});

app.use(sessionMiddleware);
```

I'm making periodically calls to my server, and I see the "expires" parameter of my cookie updates correctly, pushing the 30000 limit further.
But, for some reason, the session is destroyed and I get another session ID, again for 30000.

Here is what I use to check my session ID:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`CURRENT SESSION: ${req.session.id}`);
})
```

When I check in my browser, I see that even if the cookie expiration date changes on the server, it doesn't change in the client (browser). Is there a way to update the expiration date client-side?

I thought I could resend the cookie like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`CURRENT SESSION: ${req.session.id}`);
  res.cookie('connect.sid', req.sessionID, req.session.cookie);
})
```

But it keeps changing the cookie to another one, sometimes with the value of a correct sessionID, sometimes with 's:' followed by a value of another cookie.

I thought I could send the 'connect.sid' cookie from my client to the server to update it, but as it's a signed cookie I would have to use the same secret client-side and that is clearly not possible.

What am I doing wrong here? I thought setting "resave" to true wouldn't destroy the session.

Comment: The resave option is used to force update the session values in the session storage, even if the session has not been modified, see [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session#user-content-resave)
This option does not interact with the cookie expiration date.


For the front-end part, as you are using http only cookie, I am not sure about modifying the cookie yourself in the browser.


To be sure that express session increase the expiration date of your session, you can check with a redis client the TTL of the key that has been generated, [here](https://redis.io/commands/ttl/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you take a look to my answer? I'm using https only in development mode, in production I'm using https but this is not the problem here I think (or is it?). The `resave` option actually pushed the expiration date further, I see it in the logs. My problem was that despite the expiration date being updated on the server, the client didn't receive the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waw, that was not as easy as it should be. I finally found what to do: the problem was I had to sign the cookie with the same secret as I initialized it. For that, I had to install the `cookie-signature` package.

```
npm i --save cookie-signature
```

I create a signature function like this:

```
const signature = require('cookie-signature').sign;
```

Then, in my middleware `app.use` function, I simply had to write these lines (look at the `s:` which is added for some reason...):

```
const signedSessionId = signature(req.sessionID, SESSIONSECRET);
res.cookie('connect.sid', `s:${signedSessionId}`, req.session.cookie);
```

Like this, the expiration date of the cookie client-side is pushed further, like it is in the server-side.

Note: it's very strange that the `connect.sid` cookie doesn't update automatically client-side even though it has been updated server-side. I don't see the point of using `resave: true` if the information is not passed to the client. If I misread the documentation and there is actually a native way to do it, I'd be glad to know the way.

Comment: The express-session package handles everything for you, it already puts the cookie in the header of the response, so you normally don't have to call res.cookie yourself. I will write an answer with an example. I am surely missing something with your code, tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle your user' session with a cookie, using express-session and connect-redis, you can normally follow this example

```javascript
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const session = require('express-session')
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const clientRedis = new Redis();
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

const SESSIONSECRET = "my-secret";
const sessionMiddleware = session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    client: clientRedis,
  }),
  secret: SESSIONSECRET,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave:true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 60000,
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true,
    domain:"localhost"
   }
});
app.listen(3000);
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.session.id)
    req.session.lastAccess=new Date().toISOString();
    res.json({"hello":"session"})
})
```

The node-session already parse the cookies, so you don't need an other package for it. It also put everything in the response header automatically, so no need to set the res.cookie yourself.

EDIT : I was a bit hasty, the express-session does not give you the cookies. It parse them but does not give you the cookies on the request object. You should still use cookie-parser package, if you are interest in other cookies than the session cookie

You don't have anything else to do from what I can tell.
The TTL of the key in redis will be reset/update at the max age of the cookie, here 1 minute, and you should see the expiration date of the cookie update in the browser too.

Maybe the custom middleware you made hijacked the cookie value send in the response

Tell me if it helps you. If something still feels strange to you, tell me in comment and I will update my response.

Cheers !

Comment: Thanks for you answer. That is actually what I already did (or I have missed something?), but the cookie expiration date never updated in my client. I went crazy because I would have expected to a behaviour of auto-updating client-side.
What did you do different from what I did? I can't see the difference.There is the "`lastAccess"` but I don't have any problem with the cookie server-side, the expiration date update works fine.

Comment: The lastAcces should not change anything, it was just to see/log when the client reach the endpoint.
Not sure really, could you update your question with full code, for the middleware part ? 
I don't if you put the middleware app.use((req,res,next)=>{ res.cookie(etc)}) in it. If you update manually the cookie like this, it could potentially be the source of your error.

Comment: I was thinking about the domain property on the cookie too. It must match the domain of the caller, to be send/visible on the browser . But if you saw the cookie at first, it should be good